# Guided topic modeling: generating words from topics

Tags: r, topic-model, lda

I need to generate lists of words related to specific topics for a project. I am familiar with clustering methods of topic modeling such as LDA, but I have something else in mind. Are there any methods to generate lists of related words from a root word? For instance, where I could type "medicine" and it would return a list of words or terms related to medicine, such as "doctor", "malpractice", "office", etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using word2vec: It orders words in vector space according to context, it allows you to retrieve words with similar context.

You can find pretrained models on the web.

Comment: Thank you! This is the approach I ended up taking. It occurred to me because I was already going to be using word2vec for a later aspect of the same project.

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of building something from scratch, you should utilize the domain knowledge of experts.

One example: Turn Wikipedia's topic portals (e.g., the [medicine portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Medicine/Medicine_topics)) into 
a family tree.

Comment: Hi Elias. Very insightful answer!